# Error while creating a private route for the admin dash board

Tags: reactjs

I tried below code to private route the admin dash board
i am using react-router-dom:6.2.2. I need help to figure out private route which could be accessed only by the admin. I tried all the existing solution in the stackoverflow .

app.js

```
    <BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
    <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={<PrivateRouter><Dashboard /> </PrivateRouter>} />
   </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Private Router.js

```
        <Route
          {...rest}
          component={(props) => {
            const token = window.localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
            console.log(token)
            if (token) {
              return <Component {...props} />;
            } else {
              return <Navigate to={"/login"} />;
            }
          }}
        />
      );
    }
```

And its throwing error on console

```
index.tsx:24 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
    at invariant (index.tsx:24:1)
    at Route (index.tsx:235:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development)
```

Comment: The error exactly explains what went wrong

Comment: But even I cant use         <PrivateRouter path="/admin/dashbord" element={<Dashboard />} /> } and couldnot find any other solution

Comment: While asking questions, explain what you need, what you have tried, and what you got. You did two of them but please add what you need too, it may help your question getting an answer quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router Guard function:

```
const routerGuard = () => {
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  return !!token // if token exist, return true, else return false
}
```

Your route in `app.js`

```
<Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={routerGuard() ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only show the admin page if the token is set, then simply use a conditional return method.

your route should be very simple

```
<Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
```

you don't need PrivateRoute component.

in your dashboard use the following:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; // import this in your component

function Dashboard(props) {
const [data, setData] = useState(); // this is data you want to render
 const navigate = useNavigate(); // use this to navigate to your login
const [ready, setReady] = useState(false) // use this if you want to render data after fetching from end point or it will throw an error of undefined.
 useEffect(() => {
    // here is the logic to check your jwt
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    console.log(token)
    if (token) {
        getData(); //get the data and render the page
    } else {
         // nothing is render and user are redirected to your login page
         navigate("/login");
     }
 }, []);

// fetch data you want to display, or skip if you are using hardcoding or a context
const getData = () {
  // fetch data
  .then(data => { // use this in your fetch method
     setData(data);
     setReady(true);
  });
}
return (
  <>
   {ready && <div>
     {data.whatever}
   </div>
  </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the PrivateRoute as Layout in react-router-dom,

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"

const PrivateRoute = ()=>{
  
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    if(token){
      setIsAuthenticated(true)
    }
  },[])
  
  if(isLoading){
    return <Loader />
  }
  
  return isAuthenticated? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="<YOUR_LOGIN_PATH>" /> 
}
```

PrivateRoute could be used to wrap private components.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you will need to change the PrivateRouter.js.

```js
const PrivateRoutes = ({ children }) => {
 const token = window.localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
        console.log(token)
        if (token) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return <Navigate to={"/login"} />;
        }
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

I hope this helped. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches you can try

- use Autheniticated/Authorized and Unauthenticated components with routes, that way you dont have to worry about putting checks in every authentication/authorization routes

  ```
  const { user }  = useAuthContext()
  return user ? <AuthenticatedApp /> : <UnauthenticatedApp />
  ```

  more about this approach in [Kent C. Dodds blogs](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications)
- if major refactoring is not possible just include the route(s) conditionally

  ```
    user ? (<Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>} />) : null
  ```
- using a WithAuth HOC or component, with auth context setup like before

  ```
  const AuthenticatedView = ({ children }) => {

        const { user }  = useAuthContext()

       return user ? children : <UnauthorizedPlaceHolder />

  }

  //or with redirect
  import { Navigate, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

  const AuthenticatedView = ({ children }) => {

        const { user }  = useAuthContext()

         let location = useLocation();
         return user ? children : <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />

  }

  //usage
  const AuthDashboard = (props) => {

        return (
            <AuthenticatedView>
               <Dashboard {...props} />
            </AuthenticatedView>
        )

  }

  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<AuthDashboard/>} />
  ```

looks like you could use [subrouting](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/) for path="/admin/dashboard"