# How should Authorization be done using React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization

I am Practicing on a Project and using Rails as a api backend and React as Front end framework. I have implemented Authentication in React but now how I am got stuck at the question of how to implement authorization.
We know in Rails we use cancancan or other gem for authorization which is session based but I cant use cancancan now because My whole front-end is in rails. Are there any ways of doing this work?

Comment: This related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74326157/2122822) could guide you in the right direction, and will help you to ask more specific question

Answer (score 0):

If all the permissions are at the backend part, some of requests must return 401 and your frontend part must respond accordingly (render a popup e.g, show a message).

If you are trying to hide some unavailable parts (menu items, buttons, pages) beforehand, your frontend part must get a list of user roles / permissions from the back beforehand and render page using this infromation. You can provide this along with authentication request or as a separate request.

---

I, personally, prefer `pundit` over `cancancan`