# React Router: How to change path URL when redirect to a component by typing path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I just wanna stop the user to visit `/profile` page until the user logs in, if the user tries to visit the profile page by typing ***/profile*** manually into the path then he/she will redirect to `/login` page. So I've successfully redirected the user to the `/login` page but the path didn't change if they were redirected by typing `/profile` into the path url.

How can I change the path once the redirection is complete?

Code:-

```
//App.js

const [profileUser, setProfileUser] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            setProfileUser(user);
        } else {
            setUserName(null);
        }
    });
    }, [profileUser]);

//JSX 
return (
        <div>
            <Header loggedUser={profileUser} />
            <MainWrapper>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
                    <Route
                        path="/profile"
                        element={
                            !profileUser ? <Login /> : <Profile loggedUser={profileUser} />
                        }
                    />
                </Routes>
            </MainWrapper>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: The issue is when I'm not login to the app and then if I write `/profile`  I can see my login page perfectly but the path didn't change, means I can see `http://localhost:3000/profile` url on my login page, it should be `http://localhost:3000/login`, right? That I wanna change....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to actually redirect to the `"/login"` route instead of rendering the `Login` component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
  <Route
    path="/profile"
    element={profileUser
      ? <Profile loggedUser={profileUser} />
      : <Navigate to="/login" replace /> // <-- Redirect
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to add `relace to="your path to need to redirect"`

```
<Route path="/profile" element={profileUser ? <Profile loggedUser={profileUser} /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
```

import `Navigate` from 'react-router-dom'

Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268045/15119024) for another question regarding private routing.